# The term 'openssl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: openssl

I am trying to run my localhost server using https and i am trying to generate a private key.
I have installed openssl and have set the environment variables of "path" to "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin". I have also set the "OPENSSL_CONF" to "C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg". But when i try run the command below, it throws an error saying "The term 'openssl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
```

Comment: In PowerShell, you can check if OpenSSL is really in your PATH by running `(gci Env:Path).Value | sls OpenSSL`.  BTW, a reboot may be required if you set the SYSTEM %PATH% environment variable.  Perhaps try running it again specifying `openssl.exe`, or from a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) window.